# "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello guys i would like someone to help me fix this bug.....i would like to sign up an account but i fail whenever i click register and i get the error above...Anyone who can help me fix this 
please help me out i have tried and i can not understand why..
Below is my code for all the controllers responsible
code for the registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #include Wicked::Wizard
    #before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
def new
  super
end

def create
  super
end

protected

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    user_steps_path
  end
end
```

below is the code for the user_steps controller

```
    class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
      steps :finishing_step

      def show
        @user = User.last
        render_wizard
      end

      def update
        render_wizard
      end
    private
        def finish_wizard_path
          current_user.update_attributes(complete: true)
          redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
below is my code for the applications controller

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout :layout_by_resource
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

  before_filter do
    resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
    method = "#{resource}_params"
    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #this is where i decide that before user fills all fields he/she should be redirected to the user_steps_path
    if resource.complete?
      root_path    
    else
      user_steps_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number,
     :city, :nationality, :address_first_line, :address_second_line, :date_of_birth, 
     :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :terms_of_service )}
  end
   protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "login"
    else
      "application"
   end
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password, :is_female, :date_of_birth, :avatar) }
  end

end
```

below is my code for the form that i want to submit to the user account after confirmation from the personal email

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :middle_name, "Middle Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :middle_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :phone_number, "Phone Number" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :date_of_birth, "Date of Birth" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, start_year: 1900 %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :address_first_line, "Address (first line)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_first_line %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :address_second_line, "Address (second line)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_second_line %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :city, "City" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :city %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :nationality, "Nationality" %><br />
    <%= country_select(:user, :nationality, {selected: "UG"}) %></div>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :terms_of_service, "Agree to Terms of Service" %> <br>
    <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Register" %></div>
  <% end %>
```

For any help thanks in advance.....

Comment: You are getting your @user as nil object, so form can not contain first argument as nil. Try User.new if there is no other condition for special case.